# Xamarin.Forms: Burger IconImageSource on iOS is pixelated

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using the iconimagesource on my masterdetail page to display an icon as the burger menu. I am using a tiny icon, and it is rendered pixelated

[image]

If I were to use an image with higher res, it would be rendered bigger until it is finally leaving its container. it looks terrible.

I think I would need a custom renderer to renderer the icon here, since I cannot add atributes to the XAML:

```
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
     x:Class="InteriorCircle.Pages.MainMenu.Page_MainMenuMaster"
     Title="AD"
     IconImageSource="{OnPlatform iOS=btn_burgermenu.png}"
     >
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: ImageIcon is used as you see in the code in the root of the xaml. there i cannot set width and height

Comment: Sorry, I had midunderstood your code snippet. What class does Page_MainMenuMaster inherit from?  That base class must control how IcinImageSource is displayed - perhaps it has parameters that can be altered in your code behind.

Comment: The baseclass is content page

Comment: Ahh, thank you - I wasn't familiar with this feature of ContentPage. (I started my app a long time ago; used a custom code approach to this.) I see that Cole gave you a solution that worked. If you ever need a more elaborate solution that handles many different cases on iOS, see [Displaying an image in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/displaying-an-image). This discusses making an `"asset catalog image set"`. Apple recommends this approach rather than the older `@2x`, `@3x` solution. However, it is overkill for your simple need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use the official sample icon directly ?

Download the icon file [in this link](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/main/Navigation/FlyoutPage/iOS/Resources/hamburger%402x.png) .

If you want to use your own image , just make its dimensions as `28*30`.

[image]

And place it into `Resources` named it as `xxx@2x.png`.

[image]

Comment: I want to understand the situation. OP reports that if he makes the image larger, then it "grows" in the display, which is not wanted. You are solving by using `@2x` naming convention?  Does this work on multiple platforms, or is it up to each platform?

Comment: This is the quickest solution and it is only for iOS platform , cause op said the problem only occurs on iOS .

Comment: Thank you, that is a working solution for iOS. The problem never occured on Android.